# If $α , β$ be two arbitrary complex number then $| α +\sqrt{α^2-β^2 } |+| α - \sqrt{α^2-β^2}|$ is equal to?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $α$ , $β$ be two arbitrary complex number then $$| α +\sqrt{α^2-β^2 } |+| α - \sqrt{α^2-β^2}|$$ is equal to ?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
&\;(|\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|+|\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|)^2\\
=&\;|\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|^2+2|\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}||\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|+|\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|^2\\
=&\;|\alpha|^2+|\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|^2+2\text{Re}(\alpha\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})+2|\alpha^2-(\alpha^2-\beta^2)|+|\alpha|^2+|\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|^2-2\text{Re}(\alpha\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})\\
=&\;2|\alpha|^2+2|\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}|^2+2|\beta|^2\\
=&\;2|\alpha|^2+2|\alpha^2-\beta^2|+2|\beta|^2\\
\end{align*}